# How to create a some dataframes by count of columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I read file and split data by tabulation:

```
dict_of_dfs = set()

with open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=data_file_delimiter)
    data= list(reader)
    
with open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    while (line := f.readline().strip()):
        total_count = len(line.split(data_file_delimiter))
        dict_of_dfs.add(total_count)
```

Creating dataframes:

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame([item for item in data if len(item)==10])
```

So, in set `dict_of_dfs` I post number of possible count of columns.

Then I want to create a dataframes by `dict_of_dfs` and set columns names individually.

How to do that?

Comment: Why are we not just using `pd.read_csv()`?

Comment: Because file has different number of columns, if it is not equal I want to handle this in separated frames to be able set columns names.

Comment: So you actually have multiple CSVs in one file.